# What is the pivot of these unsorted lists

Tags: pivot

I am having a hard time understanding what the pivots of these two unsorted lists would be.

```
List 1: 2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4
List 2: 4,5,9,1,2,8,7,3
```

I'm think it's 5 for each of them but I'm not really sure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The pivot is whatever you want it to be? Are you trying to implement quicksort or something?

Comment: I have to do partition on it. That would mean choosing the first number (2 and 4) would be easiest?

Comment: choosing first number ?.... in sorted sequence?

Comment: No I mean choosing the 2 and 4 as the pivots because they are the first numbers in the unsorted list..?

Comment: if you just need partion why dont you choose **(List.length)/2 i.e. middle one**

Comment: I just did it on a piece of paper for list one. I choose 5 as the pivot and ended up with 2,4,3,1,5,7,6,8. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do quicksort.
You choose the first item of the array as pivot (you can also chose the last one if you prefer).
At the end of the Iteration you swap the pivot to where it's supposed to be.